# What is a good substitute for "hope"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

How do I make  this statement without using "*hope*" twice?  I would like to keep it short and simple, as this will be used for text messaging.

> We hope you enjoyed your visit and we hope to see you again soon.

Would something like this be better?

> We hope you enjoyed your visit and we are looking forward to seeing you again soon.

Comment: "We hope you enjoyed your visit and we see you again soon."

Answer (score -2):

Both examples need a comma after "visit" and before "and" to avoid the ungrammatical fused sentence. Beyond that, you could be more succinct with:

> We hope you enjoyed your visit and are looking forward to seeing you again soon.

(Note that there is no comma in my sentence above because the word "and" is joining two verb phrases rather than two independent clauses.)

Comment: Huh? There's no rule requiring a comma in "We hope you enjoyed your visit and we hope to see you again soon." Some sources say you need a comma before "and" if the subjects are different, but it's "we" in both cases. And other sources don't care about a comma.